# Problem connecting to isp server using xl2tpd as client. Ubuntu server 13.04

Tags: networking, server, vpn

I have followed guides found on google and ubuntu support pages and can get **xl2tpd** connection up but only under the following conditions:

1 - ADSL model must be configured and connected to the ISP

or

2 - ADSL modem in bridge mode I must have an existing PPPoe connection established.

If neither of the above are active xl2tpd wont trigger pppd and connect to the isp and thus tunnel connection fails to connect to the L2TP server of the ISP.

Am I doing something wrong;

```
/etc/ppp/options.l2tpd.axxess

ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
refuse-eap
refuse-chap
require-pap
noccp
noauth
idle 1800
mtu 1200
mru 1200
defaultroute
usepeerdns
debug
lock
connect-delay 5000
name (name used for ppp connection)
```

---

```
/etc/ppp/pap-secrets


#       *       password
(name used for ppp connection as above)    *    (ppp password supplied by isp)
```

---

```
/etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf

 [global]                                                               ; Global parameters:
 auth file = /etc/xl2tpd/l2tp-secrets   ; * Where our challenge secrets are
 access control = yes                                   ; * Refuse connections without IP match
debug tunnel = yes
 [lac axxess]
 lns = 196.30.121.50                         ; * Who is our LNS?
 redial = yes                                ; * Redial if disconnected?
 redial timeout = 5                          ; * Wait n seconds between redials
 max redials = 5                             ; * Give up after n consecutive failures
 hidden bit = yes                            ; * User hidden AVP's?
 length bit = yes                            ; * Use length bit in payload?
 require pap = yes                           ; * Require PAP auth. by peer
 require chap = no                           ; * Require CHAP auth. by peer
 refuse chap = yes                           ; * Refuse CHAP authentication
 require authentication = yes                ; * Require peer to authenticate
 name = BLA85003@axxess                      ; * Report this as our hostname
 ppp debug = yes                             ; * Turn on PPP debugging
 pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.l2tpd.axxess  ; * ppp options file for this lac
```

---

```
/etc/xl2tpd/l2tp-secrets


# Secrets for authenticating l2tp tunnels
# us    them    secret
# *             marko blah2
# zeus          marko   blah
# *     *       interop

*  vzb_l2tp   (*** secret supplied by isp)

    ^ isp server host name
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Further info;
If I use sudo pon dsl-provider to start a ppp connection on ppp99 xl2tpd will connect and create ppp0 but no traffic coming in on ppp0 from isp.

Comment: Here as a image of my layout [link](http://i.imgur.com/XWegJlq.png)
I think it might be a networking issue. I need to bridge ppp0 with eth0 once the l2tp link is up.